# Some Post Content Does Not Show Up In DB Search

Tags: mysql, post-content

I am using MySQL Workbench to search for URL's in my DB, in order to use sql's `update()` to change them to a different URL. Easy enough. What bugs me is even then, some of these URL's, nearly all of which were typed into post content sections by users, do not show up in the obvious places, like `wp_posts`, or even when I search the entire schema.

Any tips on where else `post_content` is stored, aside from `post_content`

Comment: If you use any pagebuilders or custom fields, they may be stored in `meta_value` in `wp_postmeta`. Have you tried searching for just a portion of the URL? Maybe some of the characters got escaped or encoded oddly?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress store the content from the editor inside the table `post_content`. But if you use additional plugins for your editor it is possible to store on different places, like custom tables and also in `post_meta`, really popular for third plugins to store date there use the meta API.

Small hint, maybe you should use a a plugin for search/replace in the database if you not so familiar with the search about all tables. Makes easier to find the right point there store your data.